# How to check if String contains only and only alphabets?

Tags: string

I am looking for solution to my simple problem. I want to check String if it only contains alphabets and if it contains anything else like period , special characters , then it should be reported.

For example , if my String is "abcd" , then it should return true , and if string is "ab.cd." , then it should return false.

I do not want to use Character.isLetter() for some reasons and rather interested in using Pattern.match()

Comment: which language of your question...?

Comment: `Patten.compile("^[a-z]+$")`

Comment: Hi Avinash , above regex worked.. Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Whichever Languge you use, the Buzzword you are looking for is: Regex.

A [Regex (Regular Expression)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is a character-sequance, that defines a search-pattern, you can use to match / test your strings. Implementation and syntax of the regex depends on the language you use, they can vary vastly across languages.

An example in Javascript would look like this for example:

```
var stringValid = "abaca"
var stringInalid = "ab()aca"

var pattern = /^[a-z]+$/;

// test the pattern against your string

testResult = pattern.test(stringValid); // should be true
testResult = pattern.test(stringInvalid); // should be false
```

The syntax has the following meaning: From begin (`^`) to end (`$`), every character should be in the range `[a-z]`. There has to be at least one character (`+`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply , but I believe I am still missing something. I am using java. I tried below code snippet , if (!token.toLowerCase().matches("/^[a-z]+$/")){
               System.out.println("Yes it has special characters"); } else { System.out.println("No it has no special characters , no need to fix"); }  and I passed "all." ,and it says , Yes it has special characters , but when I passed only "all" , it still says , Yes it has special characters :(

Comment: I am not so sure, as I am not a Java-developer. Maybe you could post this as a seperate question. The code-snipped above is Javascript, and only to show how regexes work in general.